# Strange bug with chdir in c

Tags: c, linux, unix, chdir

building a small shell like prog

i try to make cd command, so i use:

```
if (!strcmp(cmd, "cd") ) 
    {
        if(chdir("args[1]")!=0){
            printf(" %s - path not found\n",args[1]);
            perror("Error:");
        }
    }
```

the output is this:

```
smash > cd /home/johnny/workspace/
 /home/johnny/workspace/ - path not found
Error:: No such file or directory
smash > cd test
 test - path not found
Error:: No such file or directory
```

ps there is  a "test" folder in the working dir

pps
maybe you guys can help me on how to make "cd .." command

Comment: `chdir("args[1]")` - are you sure you have a directory named `args[1]`? Because in C string literals won't be parsed to account for variables and such, this isn't PHP. What you want to do is (probably) `chdir(args[1])` (note the lack of double quotes).

Comment: Study the source code of existing shells for inspiration

Comment: in general, a call to `perror()` needs to be immediately after the call to the system function that set errno.  The posted code, after corrections for the parameter to `chdir()`, contains an intervening call to `printf()`, which, on error, would have changed the value in `errno`.  Suggest placing the call to `perror()` immediately after the call to `chdir()`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are passing the actual string `"args[1]"` into `chdir`. This probably is not what you want bu instead you want `chdir(args[1])` So your code would look like this:

```
if (!strcmp(cmd, "cd") ) 
    {
        if(chdir(args[1])!=0){
            fprintf(stderr, "chdir %s failed: %s\n", args[1], strerror(errno));
        }
    }
```

From the output of `printf` your path seems ok, notice that in `printf` you dont have `"args[1]"` but instead you have `args[1]`.

Also as pointed by @BasileStarynkevitch in the comment bellow:

> `perror` after a `printf` is wrong (since a failed `printf` would
>   change `errno`).

And therefore you should use  the `fprintf` above.

Comment: `perror` after a `printf` is wrong (since a failed `printf` would change `errno`).  Replace both `printf` & `perror` calls with simply: `fprintf(stderr, "chdir %s failed: %s\n", args[1], strerror(errno));`